# could not find gem 'mysql2..' when running rails script/generate scaffold command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I got this error:

```
Could not find gem 'mysql2 (>= 0, runtime)' in any of the gem sources.
Try running `bundle install`.
```

when trying:

```
rails script/generate scaffold post title:string
```

I am on a mac osx, rails 1.8.7, 3.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `rails script/generate …` with rails 3.0? Maybe you upgraded rails 2.x project? With rails 3 you should use `rails generate …` or shorter `rails g …`.

About missing gem: run `bundle install` as asked for :)

Comment: ok it worked, i got the same error on ubuntu and bundle install didn't make it work, but on my mac it is working thanks.

Comment: on ubuntu: try simply installing it with `gem install mysql2`, try updating gem system `gem update --system` and installing

Answer (score 8):

On ubuntu you may need to install library for mysql first.

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

And then you can install

```
gem install mysql2
```

or even better way is to use [rvm](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/)

```
rvm gem install mysql2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Mac, this will help you (I also had been on this error for 2 hours).

```
brew install mysql

brew install openssl

gem install mysql2 -v '0.5.2' -- --with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include

bundle install
```

The main point is that you have to first install the openssl for setup the mysql2 gem on Mac.